# Photobombing without app used by Harley Davidson

Tags: visible-light, laser

[Here we see a photobombing trick](http://youtu.be/zPS1FRzQH7Y), used by Harley Davidson.

They achieve to incrust a logo on a photo you take. The logo is invisible with naked eyes and only revealed on the photo you take.

How does it work?

Comment: Tip: view the front of your remote control through your camera while pressing the buttons. You can check the batteries this way too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The camera in a smartphone is sensitive to wavelengths of light that the human eye cannot see. Have a look at this picture from [this article](http://www.maxmax.com/spectral_response.htm):

[image: Spectral response]

This is actually a Canon EOS 40D SLR, but the idea is the same. The human eye can't see any wavelengths longer than about 700nm, but the graph shows the camera can detect light out to 1000nm.

So if you project your message using light with a wavelength of, for example, 900nm your eye won't be able to see the message but the camera will, and it will appear on the photo.

Comment: “The camera in a smartphone is sensitive to wavelengths of light that the human eye cannot see.” A bit nit-picky, but lots of digital cameras—not just SmartPhone cameras—can see IR light.

Comment: As a practical test, use the "live view" on your favorite digital camera to look at the signal LED on any infrared remote controller as you press a button. The camera will show you that the LED blinks, even though you can't see it naked-eye.

Comment: Another interesting question would be *why* digital cameras are sensitive to non-visible light, considering that the usual purpose of digital photography is to reproduce the perception of the human eye.

Comment: I was always under the impression that all consumer cameras had IR filters explicitly for filtering out that light. I guess those filters are not as ubiquitous and/or sharp as I thought.

Comment: An important but crucial (maybe obvious to most, but not some) detail here is that you see the IR message on your screen because the screen is emitting the IR message it sees in the visible (some people might ask "alright, well why doesn't the screen show the message's light in the IR also?").

Comment: @ChrisWhite same here.  That the IR filter in SLRs heavily attenuates the 656nm H-Alpha emission line is commonly cited as a reason why dedicated astrophotographic  cameras are preferable for imaging nebula's.

Comment: Looking at what the company you got your graph from sells (conversion of cameras to IR/UV use by replacing stock filters), I believe the graph you're using shows the sensors response without the standard IR/UV rejection filter, not the response of an off the shelf version.

Comment: The IR filter in digital cameras is mostly there to keep them from seeing enough IR to show warm objects as distractingly bright. Rumor has it that one of the early "night shot" cameras had the ability to move this filter out of the way... until they discovered that this also allowed it to see through clothing to some degree.

Comment: You can actually see 800 nm. At least laser beams with that wavelength are easily seen - they seem red. And most used remote control IR wavelengths are about 940-980 nm. All my cameras can see both 800 nm and 980 nm laser beams, which I found out trying to shoot up-conversion in lanthanide doped crystals.